# Generate an array of parent/child page IDs, based on parent page name

Tags: php, array

I've been using the following functions (updating IDs manually) to group parent & child pages into an array, which I then use in an if/else statement to present content depending on whether or not the current page is in that array. Examples below:

```
function id_array_function() {
    $array = array(
    10, // Example Parent ID
    12, // Example Child ID
    14  // Example Child ID
  );
    return $array;
}
```

```
function content_placement_function() {
    if( is_page( id_array_example() ) ) {
    // If current page is in array, do this
    }
    else {
    // Otherwise, do this
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a reusable function which I can plug any page name into (avoiding IDs due to issues with local/production installs having different page IDs), and return an array of both the parent and any child page names for use elsewhere, such as:

```
if( is_page( id_array_function('About') ) ) { 
  // Function would return array as ('About', 'Our Company', 'Careers', 'etc...')
  // If current page is in array, do this
}
```

I've attempted this with wp_list_pages (could not return, only echo), and get_posts/get_terms (both returned empty arrays). If anyone has a pre-existing snippet or an idea as to how I could achieve the reusable function, I'd be massively appreciative of the help.

==========

EDIT: Working answer from Krzysiek below. Possible alternative option on CSS Tricks (targeting IDs): https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/if-page-is-parent-or-child/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so what we want to achieve is to write a function that will take a title of a page and return the array containing its ID and IDs of its children. So here's the code:

```
function get_page_and_its_children_ids_by_title( $page_title ) {
    $result = array();

    $page = get_page_by_title( $page_title );  // find page with given title
    if ( $page ) {  // if that page exists
        $result[] = $page->ID;  // add its ID to the result
        $children = get_children( array(  // get its children 
            'post_parent' => $page->ID,
            'post_type'   => 'page', 
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish' 
        ) );
        $result = array_merge( $result, array_keys( $children ) );  // add children ids to the result
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek. I may have misunderstood the usage, but I've updated the if/else in the content placement function as follows:

```
if( is_page( get_page_and_its_children_ids_by_title( 'About' ) ) ) { // Do this }
```

I'm still not seeing content across the parent/children in that array - how would you use the array the function has generated?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Do you have any problems using it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing the content - should '$title' and '$page_title' be separate entities, or should they be the same variable?

Comment: Ahhh... Sorry for that - simple typo - it happens when you type code on mobile ;) Yeah, they definitely should be the same - already fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect. Thanks Krzysiek - massively appreciated. Will accept as answer now and update original post.